# Chrome profiles not working properly

Tags: google-chrome

Ive been using Chromium for a while and have 2 profiles with 2 different google accounts synced with them. Works just fine. I wanted to use netflix on my linux side of things (I dual boot windows) so I uninstalled chromium and installed Chrome. All is well so far.

I log in with my google account, everything syncs up...except passwords. Passwords for some reason aren't syncing on either profile. After I log in and sync my bookmarks and whatnot, I restart chrome to see if that can get my passwords to sync.

Upon starting back up (which also isnt very quick, takes a few seconds), I'm greeted with a small popup that says "Something went wrong when opening your profile. Some features may be unavailable." This then logs me out, forcing me to log back in. This happens *every* single time I restart chrome, on either profile. On my mac, and in windows, and in chromium, both profiles work perfectly fine. It is only on Elementary and on Chrome that it is an issue.

Any ideas?

Edit: I've uninstalled Chrome (purge and rm -rf the config under /.config/google-chrome-stable) and went back to Chromium, and now chromium is doing the same thing.

Answer (score 0):

This usually happens when Chrome crashes for me as well as when I'm low on disk space or a lot of resources are being used. When those cases happen I have to enter my Google details again to sync my Chrome normally. This also happened when I was on Ubuntu 16.10. I never went to the length of looking into this issue. However, keeping tabs on cleaning cache and unused space limits the chances of Chrome presenting that issue. Those are the only times this issue happens to me.

Comment: This is on a fresh install. I have plenty of space available, and plenty of resources